# SQL Syntax - Edit a column record

Tags: sql

I have a table called `User`. In the `User` table, there's a column called `country`. How do I write an SQL syntax to change all the user records whose `country` is "a" to `country` "b"?

Comment: What have you tried?  This question shows no research effort at all.  This is a very basic `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic `update` statement:

```
UPDATE user
SET    country = 'b' -- what to change
WHERE  country = 'a' -- on which records
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update "User" set "Country" = 'b' where "Country" = 'a'
```

PS: SQL is compatible with many backends. You didn't specify which one you have. That matters, because User maybe a keyword in some backends and/or casing might be significant.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [User]
       SET [country] = 'b'      -- new value  
       WHERE [country]='a'      -- previous value
```

Comment: I don't understand what wrong with my code. I have done that for MS-SQL